# Custom edit text with borders

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, label, material-design

I am trying to put borders on edit text and put a label on it. I have made the border like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#A0A0A0" />
</shape>
```

but I am not able to achieve my desired result.

I want something like below :

[image]

please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/boarder"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="input" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:text="Label" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

boarder.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#03A6F0" />

<corners android:radius="12dp" />
```

[image: here]

Comment: share the boderedt from drawable also.

Comment: I used  your boder
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#A0A0A0" />
</shape>

Answer (score 18):

Check this link for the guidelines on creating the new Material Design textfield you want.

https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#usage

**- for how to use it:**

To create a material text field, add a TextInputLayout to your XML layout and a TextInputEditText as a direct child.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/hint_text"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Note: You can also use an EditText for your input text component. However, using TextInputEditText allows TextInputLayout greater control over the visual aspects of the input text - it allows TextInputLayout to display hint in the text field when in “extract mode” (such as landscape mode).

**- for styling it:**

*Filled Box (Default)*

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"
```

*Outline Box*

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlineBox"
```

For more, check this link:

https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

I hope this will help.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: `OutlineBox` should be `OutlinedBox`

Answer (score 3):

I know, its a bit late, but you might want to take a look at [this](https://www.yudiz.com/introduction-to-upcoming-androidx-with-material-components/) and [this](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#usage).

[image: AndroidX Material EditText]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#CDCDCE"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/si_btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_round_corner"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Inp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="#CDCDCE"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Label"
        android:textColor="#741c7a"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

below is drawable code button_round_corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke
    android:color="#741c7a"
    android:width="1dp"/>

<corners android:radius="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: what is button_round_corner ?

Comment: It's Drawable which i made, I have  edited my answer. Please check