# MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox it doesn't work properly boxBackgroundColor

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

I use material. I'm going to use a color for TextInputLayout for the backdrop, but something like the one below! hint background not change.i used style and wanted to make changes but it didn't work. In the layout itself I tried to apply the changes again! How to fix this problem?

***NOTE***

background of **label username** in picture that not **transparent** and it *covers* some of the **TextInputEditText**

[image]

in **build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

in **style**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.App.Caption</item>
        <item name="shapeAppearanceSmallComponent">@style/ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"/>


    <style name="TextAppearance.App.Subtitle1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.App.Caption" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ShapeAppearance.App.SmallComponent" parent="ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.SmallComponent">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

in **layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@color/gray"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="32dp">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/linUsername"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:hint="@string/label_username"
    android:textColorHint="#AEB0C6"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="#33385E"
    app:boxStrokeColor="@color/red"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_clear_white_24dp"
    app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
    app:endIconTint="#AEB0C6"
    app:hintTextColor="#AEB0C6"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_info_outline_white_24dp"
    app:startIconTint="#AEB0C6">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/edtUsername"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textColorHint="@color/white"
      app:hintTextColor="#AEB0C6" />

  </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSelectText"
    android:layout_width="168dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/iran_sans_mobile"
    android:text="login"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:cornerRadius="@dimen/radiusButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thankful. I am also very happy to meet you @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: Your brother works here in Mashhad?!

Comment: No, they are from my distant relatives,(Miss brother, my cousin :) ) @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem here. You can't show "username"?

Comment: Take a look at the picture, if you look at the username background , it has a problem with the color of the back and something must be transparent on the back @MohammadMoeinGolchin

Comment: This question doesn't help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401242/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outlined Edit Text from Material Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52401242/outlined-edit-text-from-material-design)

Comment: In my second answer for boarder.xml try: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
<corners android:radius="12dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#fff"/>
</shape>

Answer (score 1):

You may use custom edit text with border, so you can easily set your desired background. For example try this code:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boarder"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="input"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:endIconTint="#EF0707" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:text="Label" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectText"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

boarder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#03A6F0" />

    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

Also see here: [Custom edit text with borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619360/)

Comment: Thank you very much but it does make the animation go away if you use MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox you will notice its animation (as well as many other things such as its icons).
I want to use MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.

Comment: Hi @abolfazl bazghandi, your welcome, I give another answer with style

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like to use custom edit text, you can modify your code this way:

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="32dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/linUsername"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="username"
        android:textColorHint="#ED0A0A"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="#1A33385E"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:endIconTint="#AEB0C6">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edtUsername"
            android:background="@drawable/boarder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="User"
            android:textColorHint="#fff"
            app:hintTextColor="#AEB0C6" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectText"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="login"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cornerRadius="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in boarder.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#8033385E"/>
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

Output will be:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I had tried this way before. The problem is that it has to be the same color as the one inside the TextInputLayout.This is not the solution. It looks like a bug for com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Comment: It's possible I think. You can define a layer for textinputlayer which is wrap-content. Then you can set background for it. As you said maybe this component has bug.@abolfazl bazghandi

Comment: Thank you very much for your follow up. Definitely a bug. If I try this the way you say, the margin will be fine and not beautiful.

Comment: You mean its boarder?  You can't set boarder for its layout?@abolfazlbazghandi

Comment: Yes border,That's not good.I don't think it will, check the rocket chat :)

Comment: rocket chat :) :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: I edited my answer, it's nearer to what you want.@abolfazlbazghandi

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for. So you applied a layer to the background. This does not make TextInputLayout look like its original material. Thank you very much for following.

Comment: We can't change attributes of a style which are defined and are unchangable. You can use another style which is nearer to what you want. If you want to use this style, my solution is a trick. I didn't give layer to the background. In drawables I made a shape and set it to background of textview. You can change color of background and color of text. In this solution your style is used, too. @abolfazl bazghandi

Comment: Your opinion is correct, but I think it is a bug and it will be fixed!:)

Comment: Until it isn't fixed, my answer may be correct answer of your question!@abolfazlbazghandi

Comment: I don't think that's the answer I'm looking for.please respect the opinions of others:)