# How to fix TextInputLayout stroke on disabled floating hint

Tags: android, material-design

I'm using Material theme and TextInputLayout for a login page. It's normal until I disable hint to remove floating hint. As you can see form the password field where hint is disabled, the look is weird, the stroke is gone.

Is it the default behavior?

[image: login form]

[image: login form 2]

```kotlin
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:hint="Username">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:focusedByDefault="false"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:hint="Password">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_lock"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

---

EDIT:

We have to include material design components in our `build.gradle`, for example:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Even though we can use the widget and the default style without including the library, it seems that it might make some UI issues. Best to make make sure the library is included if we want to use material component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898946/materialcomponents-textinputlayout-outlinedbox-it-doesnt-work-properly-boxbackg/60910419#60910419

Comment: What version of Material Design Components are you using?

Comment: That's normal for the OutlinedBox style. It's meant to be used with the same background color as the activity.