# Add Double border to Text Field In Android App

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm new to Android development. I want to know is there any way to add two border in a text field. one inside another so that When User provide Input the Inner Border turns blue or specified color?

[Hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1emL.png)

Comment: You should give it custom border

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898946/materialcomponents-textinputlayout-outlinedbox-it-doesnt-work-properly-boxbackg/60910419#60910419

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate drawables for each
app the outer drawable to a linear layout and inside that linear layout put edittext and apply second drawable to that edittext